# How to return a value of an async function when there's a query inside a for

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to return a value after a for loop has been completed, the for loop is inside an async function.
Inside the loop, there's a query that inserts to the db.

The function is working ok, but when i use postman, the response returns empty (even tho the values have been inserted to the db)

Here's how i call the function:

```
        insertarPracticas(turno_id,req.body.lista_codigos_practicas, queryInsertarPracticas)
        .then( result=> {
                 res.status(200).json({
                      "Practicas Agregadas": result
                    })
                 }
        )
```

And here's the function:

```
async function insertarPracticas(turno_id, req, queryInsertarPracticas){
//practicasAgregadas="";
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i=0; i< req.length; i++){ 
        connection.query(
            queryInsertarPracticas, [turno_id, req[i]],(error2, row2) => { 
                if (error2) {
                    console.log("Error al insertar turno detalle (prácticas): "+req[i] +" "+ error2);             
                    practicasNoAgregadas += req[i] + "-";                   
                }else{
                    console.log("Turnos detalle agregados "+req[i]);
                    practicasAgregadas += req[i] + "-"; 
                    console.log("practicas "+practicasAgregadas);
                }
        });
        console.log("en for "+practicasAgregadas);
    }
    resolve(practicasAgregadas)

    // Or of there was an error
    reject("error");
})
```

What's happening here is that the function won't wait for the connection query to end, even tho it inserts values to the db, on Postman i get the first result, which is empty:

[image]

But i do have the values inserted on my database.

What's the correct way to handle this? I've tried using map instead of for, and now i'm trying with promise, but i'm not sure i'm using it correctly.

Here's the console, where you can see that the console.log("en for" + practicasAgregadas) returns empty, when it should have some values.

Comment: `connection.query` is asynchronous. You should use `Promise.all` to wait for all those queries to finish

Answer (score 1):

after your map, just use:

```
await Promise.all(yourArray);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @hakikayoub i have a question tho, i was able to make it return 3 values, they return null. How do i set the values to the res constant? https://codeshare.io/K8wexo

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you built your connection file, but you should change it to an async function and await the connection.query

Comment: i don't have a connection file, its just a constant:

https://codeshare.io/zy6rwD